# Why zero-initialize when it's not necessary

Tags: c++, initialization, theory

I'm starting C++ and saw the Author of the course/tutorial zero-initialize a variable and started wondering why is zero-initializing even an option? You could just identify the variable and assign a value later. Is there a performance benefit? Or so readers can understand the code better?

C++ example:

opt1:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x{ }; //<-- difference here
    std::cout << "Enter a number: "; 
    std::cin >> x; 
    std::cout << "You entered: " << x << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

opt2:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x; //<-- difference here
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "You entered: " << x << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

You will get the same outputs with both options.

Maybe It's me forgetting something trivial (and also not finding it online).

Comment: In older versions of C++ if `std::cin` failed it would leave the object unmodified. So in older versions of C++ the second example was actually Undefined Behavior if `std::cin` failed. In newer versions of C++ the second option is fine.

Comment: That's something to keep in mind with any API call.  Sometimes the "out"  parameters are only changed on success.

Comment: If you zero initialize an `int` where it would always be overwritten before being read, I would expect the compile to be able to make that determination and remove the initialization. So it is usually not harmful to explicitly initialize your variables even if it is not necessary.

Comment: @DaveS What do you mean by 'success'?

Comment: @SamimMaschal functions can either succeed or fail. In the case of console I/O, a read operation could fail if the console fails for some unknown reason at the OS layer (ie, out of memory, etc), or if the user's input simply does not match what the read is expecting (ie, user enters letters where integers are expected, etc). If any function has an output value indicating the success/failure state, you should always pay attention to it.

Comment: Some hints: http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-always and http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es22-dont-declare-a-variable-until-you-have-a-value-to-initialize-it-with.

Comment: What happens if you enter "z" into both programs? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz they should both output 0 in Visual Studio since the variables are of type `int`.

Comment: @SamimMaschal You think both pieces of code zero-initialize `x`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't think so. In opt2 I only identified the variable but did not give it a value until `std:cin`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no visible difference in your code.

Consider someone modifies the code to see the value of `x` before user input is taken. Then this is completely fine:

```
int x{ }; //<-- difference here
std::cout << "x before: " << x << '\n';
std::cin >> x; 
std::cout << "You entered: " << x << '\n';
return 0;
```

While this code:

```
int x; //<-- difference here
std::cout << "x before : " << x << '\n';
std::cin >> x;
```

has [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). The code is ill-formed and compilers are not required to issue an error or warning. Most compilers are nice enough to warn for the above code, but that is nothing you can count on in general. Hence, undefined behavior is to be avoided at all costs.

The widely accepted guidelines is to always intialize variables. In other words, only declare a variable when you can initialize it. See for example the C++ CoreGuideline [ES.20:Always initialize an object](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es20-always-initialize-an-object).

Not always you can give a variable a meaningful value on initialization. This is the case with `x` in your example. Since `std::cin` will always assign something to `x` (this was different before C++11) we don't really care what is the value of `x` before. Nevertheless, following the guideline we should write `int x{};` instead of `int x;`.

Note that before C++11 the value was left untouched when extraction from the stream failed, hece such code

```
 int x;
 std::cin >> x;
 std::cout << x;
```

was wrong and dangerous. As mentioned, this changed with C++11 (now zero is written to `x` when extraction fails). The conclusion however is still the same: You better initialize `x` already when you declare it.

Comment: What if the input operation fails? Doesn't that leave `x` at its prior value?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz if it fails `0` is written since C++11. Don't ask me why. Its the one change I wonder why it was made the most

Comment: @idclev463035818: Didn't you just explain why it was made? To prevent that code from exhibiting UB? Since input errors aren't (by default) exceptions, setting the value to something that is defined is the most reasonable behavior, since errors are ignored.

Comment: @NicolBolas kind of, yes. I am just not fully convinced by my own argumentation. My naive guess is that most code that was UB before now still has a bug, but maybe removing UB from some code is already justification enough for the change

Answer (score 0):

The author explained in the very next chapter why it is beneficial to not use uninitialized variables.

> "Take care to avoid all situations that result in undefined behavior, such as using uninitialized variables".

Still, it should not be a problem if you know that everything is defined.

Source:
https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/uninitialized-variables-and-undefined-behavior/